# I can not see the line in my histogram immediatly

Tags: r, histogram, curve

I have a small problem.

When plotting a histogram with a line, the line does not show up immediately. I have to plot it 2 times and than switch back to the first plot to see the actual line.

```
hist(df$column, 
     col = "lightgreen", 
     main = "The BMI of the players",
     xlab = "BMI", 
     ylab = "Amount of players", 
     xlim=c(20, 30),
     breaks = 20, 
     freq=FALSE) # close hist
lines(density(df$column), col="blue", lwd=2)) # lines is a different command
```

So run the code and see this:

[image: Histogram without a line]

After running it for the second time I get the same plot. However, when I click the arrow to see my previous plot, I see the plot that I wanted in the first place (the one with the line!)

[image: Histogram with a line]

Does somebody know how I get the histogram WITH the line immediately

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: i don't have the data to reproduce this but my guess is, that your `lines()` command shouldn't be tab'd (be on the same line as `hist()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the call to `lines` in the call to `hist`,  `hist` will do a plot and `lines` will add a line to the previous plot, because they are called at the same moment.

Try:

```
hist(df$column, col = "lightgreen", breaks = 20)
lines(density(df$column), col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

to get it on the plot straightaway

Comment: Thanks for the solution AND explenation! <3

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
  hist(df$column, 
         col = "lightgreen", 
         main = "The BMI of the players",
         xlab = "BMI", 
         ylab = "Amount of players", 
         xlim=c(20, 30),
         breaks = 20, 
         freq=FALSE) # close hist
  lines(density(df$column), col="blue", lwd=2)) # lines is a different command
```